# FFMpeg filters compilation on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, ffmpeg

I have compiled FFMPEG on CentOS 6.6 using this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos
But, whenever I issue command

> ffmpeg -filters

The output is

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Filters:
```

Which looks to me like there is no filters compiled.
How could I ensure that I have at least scale and decimate filters? I could not find anything on this matter in Internet. Maybe seeking incorrectly?

Comment: `0.6.5` is the old, previously installed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `PATH`

The guide places the binary in `~/bin`.

A vanilla, minimal installation of CentOS 6 & 7 has `~/bin` in the `PATH` as set by `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

You can double-check with `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
```

You may have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` or simply log out and then log in for it to notice.

Alternatively you could relocate the binary elsewhere in your `PATH`, but, depending where you place it, that is not usually recommended due to the potential of conflicts with repository packages.

## `./`

Another method is to navigate to the directory containing the binary and executing it with `./`:

```
cd ~/bin
./ffmpeg -i input … output
```

## Full path

A third method is to provide the full path to the binary:

```
/home/user/bin/ffmpeg -i input … output
```

or if it is in your home directory:

```
~/bin/ffmpeg -i input … output
```